# For some reason heroku continues to stop randomly

Tags: heroku

Every time I deploy my app it works for like 6 hours and then just stops. sometimes its 3 hours sometimes its a day, it randomly stops and I want it to run 24/7. Its a discord bot and I've already tried runtimerobot or whatever. Any fixes?

Comment: are you using free dynos?